# Sending Emails with AWS SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, email-validation, amazon-ses

I cant seem to get AWS emails working. I have set up thunderbird to handle the outgoing emails (SMTP) and have set the incoming emails up to be put in a s3 Bucket. The reciving part works well, however I seem to be only able to send to those emails that I have "verified." What could the cause of this be?

Also if anyone had any tips on how to set up my email better I would also be interested. Ideally I would like to be able to send and recieve domain emails via gmail / or another web based service. I have heard AWS has something called workmail, but really I am looking for somthing free. Had this set up, it was working nicely, but seemed to stop working, and I cant seem to fix it: (tells me the MX records are not configured correctly, but I did have it working, the MX records are the same as what they were when it was working)

http://improvmx.com/

Comment: Have you got a verified domain yet? Or just verified an individual email address?

Comment: Yes I have verified the domain, added the _amazonses. TXT record MX and all that CNAME jazz. The domain is hosted at route 53

Comment: Have you increased the limits so you are no longer in sandbox mode? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html

Comment: Yes if your account is in sandbox mode you can only send emails to verified email address.

Comment: Amazon SES is designed for improving the deliverability of bulk outgoing emails. Since you "would like to be able to send and receive domain emails via gmail", I would recommend using Gmail.

Comment: "Ideally I would like to be able to send and recieve domain emails via gmail / or another web based service." Seems like you are looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Brett and error you hit the nail on the head. If you write an answer I will accept it. Andreas - I thought about that, but I did not want to pay $4 a month, but thanks for your help. John, cant work out if you were taking the pi** but I want to say a big thank you anyway. Because of your comment I did a bit of googling, turns out you can use gmail, for domain emails its called https://apps.google.com/ I also came across a service called Zoho https://www.zoho.com/mail/ This allows me to handle email for Free. Same as Workmail/Gmail, only free